# My web form works in the development environment, but not when deployed to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, azure, visual-studio-2015

Using: Visual Studio 2015, C#, on a Surface Pro 3, running Windows 10 Pro
Skill level: novice

I created a personal website and deployed it to Azure hosting. In one of my web forms, I select a type of reference from a DropDownList control (book, article, monograph, etc). Then, I enter several pieces of citation data into TextBox controls. Then I press a Button. All of the TextBox data is written to an XML file. Also, there are a series of if-then statements in the .aspx.cs code behind. Only one of the if-then statements will be true, based upon the DropDownList SelectedItem. So, for example, if SelectedItem is "Monograph" then the text in the TextBoxes will be appended to a string and formatted according to the format for citing to a monograph in a footnote.

.cs exerpts...

```
string referenceType = ddlType.SelectedItem.Text;
...
if (referenceType == "Monograph")
{
    longCite = "<span style='font-variant:small-caps'>" + author + "</span>";
    longCite = longCite + "<span style='font-variant:small-caps'>" + fullTitle + "</span>";
    pin1 = longCite;
    pin2 = " (";
    if (txtPublisher.Text.Trim() != "") { pin2 = pin2 + txtPublisher.Text.Trim(); }
    pin2 = pin2 + ", " + fullDate + ")" + country + URL;
    longCite = pin1 + pin2;
}
```

The strings built in the code above is written to a childnode of an XML file (excerpts below)...

```
            XDocument xRef = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("ref",
                new XElement("id", txtID.Text),
                new XElement("type",
                    new XAttribute("id", ddlType.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                    ddlType.SelectedItem.Text),
                new XElement("author",
                    new XAttribute("alpha", txtAuthorAlpha.Text),
                    txtAuthor.Text),
                new XElement("title", txtTitle.Text),
                new XElement("titlePrefix", txtTitlePrefix.Text),
                new XElement("subtitle", txtSubtitle.Text),
                new XElement("subDivider", txtSubDivider.Text),
                new XElement("language",
                    new XAttribute("id", ddlLanguage.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("display", ddlLanguage.SelectedItem.Text),
                    fullLang),
                new XElement("country", 
                    new XAttribute("id", ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("name", ddlCountry.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    ),
                new XElement("countries", txtCountries.Text.Trim()),
                new XElement("publisher", txtPublisher.Text),
                new XElement("date",
                    new XAttribute("day", ddlDay.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("month", ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("year", txtYear.Text),
                    fullDate),
                new XElement("longURL", txtLongURL.Text),
                new XElement("shortURL", txtShortURL.Text),
                new XElement("pin1", pin1),
                new XElement("pin2", pin2),
                new XElement("shortCite", shortCite),
                new XElement("longCite", longCite),
                new XElement("notes", txtNotes.Text)
            )
        );
        xRef.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/references/" + txtID.Text + ".xml"));
```

This works perfectly when I build and test it in the development environment. When I attempt it on Azure, it does not work.  The XML file is created properly, with all of the nodes filled in, except for the pin1, pin2, and longCite nodes that are built within the if-then statement.

I have republished the entire site. I have republished the specific webform and code behind. I have deleted the XML files and recreated them in the web form on the local server and then again on the Azure server. Two identical websites.  Two different results. When running it on my local machine, I set breakpoints within the if-then statement and it hits the breakpoints. I viewed the web form while it runs on the Azure server to ensure that the proper item on the DropDownList is selected and spelled correctly

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlType" id="MainContent_ddlType">
...
<option selected="selected" value="monograph">Monograph</option>
```

Any ideas? Is there a known Azure and/or Visual Studio bug that I should be working around?

Comment: Why didn't you set breakpoints when it was running in Azure and check it there? Why not add logging to your application using Serilog or NLog etc?

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could do that. Is there an online tutorial showing how? I'm a novice.

Comment: Yes, there's tutorials. For Azure breakpoints, it's simple if you have VS 2017. Why aren't you using the latest? Go to View > Cloud Explorer. Make sure you're signed into your Azure account (click the little person icon). Make sure you select your subscription. Then drill down to the app service, right click and Attach Debugger. You'll probably need to deploy a Debug build, not a Release build.

Comment: For logging, you should look into [Serilog](https://serilog.net/). To start with you can log to a file, but eventually you should look into something like [Seq](https://getseq.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I stepped away from this for a couple days. Then, hoping for a different outcome despite doing the same thing repeatedly, I republished (for about the fourth or fifth time).  This time, everything works.  I have no idea why.  Maybe it takes Azure servers time to make certain types of updates?  Maybe my original attempts to publish went to a new server during a migration?  In any case, it works now.